# Ember how to change Ember boostrap Tooltip background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-bootstrap

Currently I'm using [Ember Bootstrap Tooltip](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/components/tooltip) component, I read the doc, I didn't found anything about custom Background-color. It will be helpful if someone show me how to do it.

Comment: this may be a better question for their issue tracker: https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/issues (where the ember-bootstrap experts are)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I did it. they have to add @color parameter to the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered by [Simon Ihmig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5556104/simon-ihmig) one of the maintainers of [Ember Bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/issues/1724).

> You don't apply any styling via JS, you customize the BS components as you would for any other Bootstrap-based project. If using plain CSS (not recommended), you would need to override the default styles using CSS, If using Sass (recommended!), you can just tweak the related Sass variables. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#variables (this is BS v5)